# file.seek() and read() relative to the current position

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read part of a file into a bytearray but without success. I would use an extra pair of eyes, it is probably something obvious.

Example file segment:

```
...line one\nline two\nline three\nfourth line\n
                                   ^        
                                   |___ fp.tell()
```

After `fp.seek(-1,os.SEEK_CUR)` and `print fp.read(1)` output is (as expected) `\n`.

If on the other hand I execute `fp.seek(-2,os.SEEK_CUR)`, instead of the expected `e\n` output is `\nf`.

After that, I tried with `fp.seek(-3,os.SEEK_CUR)` and `print fp.read(3)` and output is `e\nf`.

In other words, bytes are read "both ways" (to the left and to the right) regardless of strictly negative pointer motion. I am sure that I am missing something here. Any hints?

Edit: It's on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you reading a file in text mode (default unless [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is called with b in the mode string) on Windows? If so, it likely has `'\r\n'` newlines, which are two bytes large, but translated to just `'\n'` by stripping the `'\r'` when you read. From [`help(file.seek)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek): "If the file is opened in text mode, only offsets returned by tell() are legal."

This would explain your symptoms, as you'd actually be reading `'\n'`, `'\r\nf'` and `'e\r\nf'` with any `'\r'` removed in each case.

Comment: That was the problem exactly. Switching to binary mode and unix style line endings solved it.